# codeigniter not recognizing some validation

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

So I have simple registration form and for some weird reason, some of the validation works and some doesn't. I defined a separate language folder for the language in conern i.e. arabic. it works for username, password and password confirmation, but not rest of the fields. What is going wrong?

```
 public function registration()
     {      
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('fullname', 'الاسم الكامل', 'isset | required | alpha');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'اسم المستخدم', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'كلمة السر', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'إعادة كلمة السر', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'الايميل', 'required |email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'المدينة', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'صورة الملف الشخصي', 'upload_no_file_selected');


            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
               $this->index();
            }
            else{
               $this->user_model->add_user();
               $this->thank();
            }

      }
```

form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>

</head>
<body dir="rtl">

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('membership/registration'); ?>

<h5>الإسم الكامل</h5>
<input type="text" name="fullname" value="" size="80" />

<h5>اسم المستخدم</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

<h5>كلمة السر</h5>
<input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />

<h5>إعادة كلمة السر</h5>
<input type="text" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />

<h5>الايميل</h5>
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50" />

<h5>المدينة</h5>
<select name="city">
  <option value="riyadh">الرياض</option>
  <option value="jeddah">جدة</option>
  <option value="dhahran">الظهران</option>
  <option value="mecca">مكة</option>
</select>

<h5>صورة الملف الشخصي</h5>
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
<br><br>

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Appreciate the help,

Comment: Have you loaded the appropriate libraries and helpers at the constructor of the controller or at the autoload configuration file?

Comment: Yes I've done. there are validations being carried on for username, password and passconf. but not any other fields.

Comment: If you try to put english characters on the validation rules does it work?

Comment: I am not pushing anything mate. I left it blank so it should catch it anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the spaces between the validation rules like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('fullname', 'الاسم الكامل', 'isset|required|alpha');
```

Comment: haha thanks mate I just posted the same answer to my own question

Comment: I am glad you found it.
I had not noticed the spaces the first time i saw your code :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer and oh is it silly! Just delete the spaces between the validation rules and it all works! so e.g.

```
alpha|isset|required
```